# ASP.Net MVC Basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

My application requires 2 login mechanisms, one is Basic Authentication giving credentials in windows security dialog, the other way is kind of faking Basic Authentication meaning an encrypted username, password is sent as part of url in  querystring say http://myurl.com?username=xxx&pwd=xxxxx
I have created a customModule like below

```
public class mymodule:IhttpModule
{

 public void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        if(context.Request.Querystring["username"]!=null)
        {
          //then write the cookie
          createcookie();
        }
        else
        {
            //Request user for Basic authentication
            context.Request.Headers["Authorization"])
        }

 }
}
```

1) When I call the URL like this http://myurl.com?username=xxx&pwd=xxxxx first request goes to AuthenticateRequest and cookie gets created, but  the AuthenticateRequest gets called for multiple times and at one point Request.QueryString is null and it executes the line context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]) and it triggers Windows Security Dialog(basic authentication), how do I achieve my requirement.

Comment: You do realise how insecure *both* these approaches are? Unless you intend on using SSL.

Comment: Yes it does happen in SSL